# How to check if you are in the first iteration of a loop in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I could understand if the question doesn't really clarify my problem, so here is some more explanation:

I am trying to add the string  "+" at the start of my string, which I get like this:

```
printLine :: [Int] -> String  --Type of the function
printLine [] = ""             --Base case

printLine (x:xs) = "+" ++ foldr (++) "+" f ++ printLine xs
                 where f = replicate x "-"
```

The result I get from the above:

```
+-----++------++------++------+
```

The result I would like to get:

```
+-----+------+------+------+
```

Basically my question is: How do I add "+" only at the start? 
I can understand that this might be a silly question, but I am stuck for a while now and I can't find the answer on SO or elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proposal: don't detect when you're in the first iteration, which is hard; instead detect when you're in the last iteration, which is easy because it's the `[]` case in the first line.

```
printLine :: [Int] -> String
-- final iteration; add an extra + at the end
printLine [] = "+"

-- not the final iteration; don't include a + at the end of the -s
printLine (x:xs) = "+" ++ replicate x '-' ++ printLine xs
```

Comment: The only potential problem is that the base case here might be to return the empty string if the input list is empty :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My version satisfies a nice invariant: the string returned always begins and ends with a `+`.

Comment: yes I agree, in the question however, it seems like the base case is that empty lists should map to empty strings, but personally I like a more "simpler" version as well. :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The question's implementation is wrong, as specified by the question asker, and the specification of the correct behavior is incomplete; therefore some taste is required in cooking up a fix. In such a situation, I prefer uniformity, simplicity, and generality until there is a reason to dislike it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you know the variant which includes foldr? That would be the one I would like to use

Comment: @ramonabacherli, you can mechanically transform this answer into one that uses `foldr` if that's what your assignment requires.

Comment: @ramonabacherli, you should look for the "`foldr` pattern" in Daniel Wagner's code. Have you learned how to recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

If an empty list must map to an empty string, one option is to fold with a special case for an empty list.

```
printLine :: [Int] -> String
printLine [] = ""
printLine xs = foldr (\x res -> '+' : replicate x '-' ++ res) "+" xs
```

So that

```
λ> map printLine [[], [1..4], [5]]
["","+-+--+---+----+","+-----+"]
```

Alternatively, since the original question asked for control during the first iteration, one option is to use a helper function. Here are two alternatives.

```
printLine' :: [Int] -> String
printLine' [] = ""
printLine' xs = '+' : go xs
  where go :: [Int] -> String
        go [] = ""
        go (n:ns) = replicate n '-' ++ "+" ++ go ns

printLine'' :: [Int] -> String
printLine'' xs = go True xs
  where go :: Bool -> [Int] -> String
        go _ [] = ""
        go isFirst (n:ns) = (if isFirst then "+" else "")
          ++ replicate n '-' ++ "+" ++ go False ns
```

With these definitions

```
λ> map printLine' [[], [1..4], [5]]
["","+-+--+---+----+","+-----+"]
λ> map printLine'' [[], [1..4], [5]]
["","+-+--+---+----+","+-----+"]
```